# Jurisdiction stripping

Tags: united-states, constitution

According to the [Wikipedia article "Jurisdiction stripping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisdiction_stripping):

> Congress may effectively eliminate any judicial review of certain federal legislative or executive actions and of certain state actions, **OR** alternatively transfer the judicial review responsibility to state courts by "knocking [federal courts] ... out of the game."

<sup>**BOLDING** added.</sup>

From this clause one may understand that congress can eliminate judicial review altogether for some action and not just transfer to a state court.

What is or can be the reference for this claim (in this article or anywhere else)?

Comment: Isn't that explained in the previous Wikipedia sentence? "This court-limiting power is granted in the Exceptions Clause (Art. III, § 2)." Are you doubting that's true or did you just miss it? Wikipedia also discusses limits (to this stripping) in a later section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [same article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurisdiction_stripping):

> Congress may define the jurisdiction of the judiciary through the simultaneous use of two powers. First, Congress holds the power to create (and, implicitly, to define the jurisdiction of) federal courts inferior to the Supreme Court (i.e. Courts of Appeals, District Courts, and various other Article I and Article III tribunals). This court-creating power is granted both in the congressional powers clause (Art. I, § 8, Cl. 9) and in the judicial vesting clause (Art. III, § 1). Second, Congress has the power to make exceptions to and regulations of the appellate jurisdiction of the Supreme Court. This court-limiting power is granted in the Exceptions Clause (Art. III, § 2).

This cites:  Bauman, Richard and Kahana, Tsvi. The Least Examined Branch: the Role of Legislatures in the Constitutional State, [p. 442](https://books.google.com/books?id=0KpYkm9SJvAC&pg=PA442) (2006).

Article I, Section 8, Clause 1 of the [constitution](https://constitutionus.com/) starts:

> The Congress shall have Power To ...

A number of powers are enumerated, including Article I, Section 8, Clause 9:

> To constitute Tribunals inferior to the supreme Court;

From Article III, Section 1:

> The judicial Power of the United States, shall be vested in one supreme Court, and in such inferior Courts as the Congress may from time to time ordain and establish.

From Article III, Section 2, Clause 2:

> In all the other Cases before mentioned, the supreme Court shall have appellateJurisdiction, both as to Law and Fact, with such Exceptions, and under such Regulations as the Congress shall make.